# fill_between in new version of matplotlib gives an error "where size does not match"

Tags: python, matplotlib

As title says, I didn't have any problem running following code in previous matplotlib (3.2.1) but got an error message after installing new version (3.5.1) of matplotlib. I googled possible solutions in vain. Would appreciate any hint to resolve this problem.

Code:

```
       axs[irow, icol].plot(wavelengths, np.mean(spec_mat[y == i + 1, :], axis=0).T, colors[i], linewidth=lw)
        if is_conf:
            print(f"wavelengths: {wavelengths.shape}")
            print(f"Quantiles: {np.quantile(spec_mat[y == i + 1, :], 0.025, axis=0).shape}")
            axs[irow, icol].fill_between(wavelengths,
                                 np.quantile(spec_mat[y == i + 1, :], 0.025, axis=0).T,
                                 np.quantile(spec_mat[y == i + 1, :], 0.975, axis=0).T,
                                 colors[i], alpha=alpha)
```

Error

```
  File "draft\utils.py", line 2487, in draw_average_spectra_preprocessing_per_class
    axs[irow, icol].fill_between(wavelengths,
  File "draft\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1412, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "draft\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5252, in fill_between
    return self._fill_between_x_or_y(
  File "draft\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5171, in _fill_between_x_or_y
    raise ValueError(f"where size ({where.size}) does not match "
ValueError: where size (1) does not match x size (175)
```

Comment: Would you please share some data, or at least the shape of `wavelengths` and `spec_mat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I found the solution after writing this post. I have to use color keyword in new version. The following line resolved the problem:

```
            axs[irow, icol].fill_between(wavelengths,
                                 np.quantile(spec_mat[y == i + 1, :], 0.025, axis=0).T,
                                 np.quantile(spec_mat[y == i + 1, :], 0.975, axis=0).T,
                                 color=colors[i], alpha=alpha)
```